# Como implementar una web scraping en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, scraping

Amigos estoy trabajando en un proyecto en wordpress en el cual tengo que implementar lo siguiente:

1) Buscador personalizado de google (listo)

2) El resultado extraer un valor de un producto x y comparar con mi web (problemas)

Pues ya pude implementar el buscador de google en mi wordpress pero la cosa es que el resultado genera un enlace que me redirecciona a la web en ecuestion, pero lo que trato de hacer es optener de la respuesta un valor en especifico y mostralo, esto se que se hace con web scraping, para esto e optado por usar el google custom serach api que retorna un json ejemplo:

```
{
"kind": "customsearch#search",
"url": {
    "type": "application/json",
    "template": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q={searchTerms}&num={count?}&start={startIndex?}&lr={language?}&safe={safe?}&cx={cx?}&sort={sort?}&filter={filter?}&gl={gl?}&cr={cr?}&googlehost={googleHost?}&c2coff={disableCnTwTranslation?}&hq={hq?}&hl={hl?}&siteSearch={siteSearch?}&siteSearchFilter={siteSearchFilter?}&exactTerms={exactTerms?}&excludeTerms={excludeTerms?}&linkSite={linkSite?}&orTerms={orTerms?}&relatedSite={relatedSite?}&dateRestrict={dateRestrict?}&lowRange={lowRange?}&highRange={highRange?}&searchType={searchType}&fileType={fileType?}&rights={rights?}&imgSize={imgSize?}&imgType={imgType?}&imgColorType={imgColorType?}&imgDominantColor={imgDominantColor?}&alt=json"
},
"queries": {
    "request": [
        {
            "title": "Google Custom Search - rtx 2080 ti",
            "totalResults": "2910",
            "searchTerms": "rtx 2080 ti",
            "count": 10,
            "startIndex": 1,
            "inputEncoding": "utf8",
            "outputEncoding": "utf8",
            "safe": "off",
            "cx": "015198498395465155114:vqhysah7n0c"
        }
    ],
    "nextPage": [
        {
            "title": "Google Custom Search - rtx 2080 ti",
            "totalResults": "2910",
            "searchTerms": "rtx 2080 ti",
            "count": 10,
            "startIndex": 11,
            "inputEncoding": "utf8",
            "outputEncoding": "utf8",
            "safe": "off",
            "cx": "015198498395465155114:vqhysah7n0c"
        }
    ]
},
"context": {
    "title": "Amazon"
},
"searchInformation": {
    "searchTime": 0.97442,
    "formattedSearchTime": "0,97",
    "totalResults": "2910",
    "formattedTotalResults": "2.910"
},
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "customsearch#result",
        "title": "EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti XC GAMING - Tarjeta ... - Amazon.com",
        "htmlTitle": "EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti XC GAMING - Tarjeta ... - Amazon.com",
        "link": "https://www.amazon.com/-/es/EVGA-GeForce-RTX-2080-GAMING/dp/B07KVKRLG2",
        "displayLink": "www.amazon.com",
        "snippet": "Amazon.com: EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti XC GAMING - Tarjeta gráfica (11 GB, \nGDDR6, doble HDB, RGB LED): Computers & Accessories.",
        "htmlSnippet": "Amazon.com: EVGA GeForce <b>RTX 2080 Ti</b> XC GAMING - Tarjeta gráfica (11 GB, <br>\nGDDR6, doble HDB, RGB LED): Computers &amp; Accessories.",
        "cacheId": "FTcuOt5oWI4J",
        "formattedUrl": "https://www.amazon.com/-/es/EVGA...RTX-2080.../B07KVKRLG2",
        "htmlFormattedUrl": "https://www.amazon.com/-/es/EVGA...<b>RTX</b>-<b>2080</b>.../B07KVKRLG2",
        "pagemap": {
            "scraped": [
                {
                    "image_link": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81mArBzBVJL._SX355_.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "cse_thumbnail": [
                {
                    "width": "259",
                    "height": "194",
                    "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRoti3RgvT9g3SQg8hGY0zYHNo-v2F43xGcDLzbx4mjsvtUt8wi2dTjJZc"
                }
            ],
            "metatags": [
                {
                    "og:url": "http://www.amazon.com/dp/B07KVKRLG2/ref=tsm_1_fb_lk",
                    "og:title": "EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Ftw3 Ultra, Overclocked, 2.75 Slot Extreme Cool Triple + iCX2, 65C Gaming, RGB, Metal Backplate, 11GB GDDR6, 11G-P4-2487-KR",
                    "og:description": "The EVGA GeForce RTX K-series graphics cards are powered by the all-new NVIDIA Turing architecture to give you incredible new levels of gaming realism, speed, power efficiency, and immersion. With the EVGA GeForce RTX K-series gaming cards you get the best gaming experience with next generation g...",
                    "og:image": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41dKhf-k2nL._SR600,315_SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg",
                    "title": "Amazon.com: EVGA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti XC GAMING - Tarjeta gráfica (11 GB, GDDR6, doble HDB, RGB LED): Computers & Accessories"
                }
            ],
            "cse_image": [
                {
                    "src": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81mArBzBVJL._SX355_.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Como pueden ver, en `items` me devuelve todos los resultados, bien todo, ingreso a la url y obtengo lo que quiero, perfecto esto lo tengo en un proyecto separado de java, la cuestion es que ahora se solicita que se haga eso mismo pero en wordpress, y la verdad no tengo ni idea de como hacer el web scraping en wordpress, alguien podria ayudarme en hacer esto.

Comment: Ok y con esa fuente que has intentado ya?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo lo mejor es no inventar la rueda, con este plugin puedes hacer el screaping que quieras. Octolooks Scrapes. Luego puedes crear un plugin que haga la comparación con get_posts($arg), allí pasas el post type = 'posts'. y en base a la consulta haces lo que necesites.

Comment: osea le explico, lo que se quiere lograr es algo asi como el comparador de precios de trivago, se implementa el buscador por que se tiene que buscar dentro de casi toda la web las paginas referentes a lo que se quiere, por eso es lo del buscador y se que eso se hace asi con web scraping, esto lo tengo alli mas o menos implementado en java, pero ahora se necesita hacerlo en wordpres, y es eso lo que no se hacer